# How to display custom post type taxonomy in Contact Form 7 text field

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, plugin-contact-form-7

I am developing a travel website but I am going to create a simple custom post type since the website will not have a complex feature for now.
In this regard, is there any way to fetch/display where the specific post has a taxonomy, for example "Destination" is "Europe". In the contact form, the destination field should automatically display "Europe" in the text field.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: At first glance you can't do this with a hook: you'd need to do this in CF7's get_default_option but there's nothing to hook in there. Instead you probably need to set 'default:shortcode' on the field and pass Destination=Europe to the shortcode.

Comment: You might do better asking CF7 for support directly, though.

Comment: the [Smart grid extension](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-grid-layout/) allows you to pre-fill a form prior to it being loaded.  See this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zPPD5VBF78w).  You will need to capture the destination  [value from the page request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829632/get-current-category-id-of-the-active-page) in order to pre-fill your text field.